# Choose which properties will be serialized

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

in my program I need to store object in XML. But I dont want all properties to be serialized to xml. How should I do that ?

```
public class Car implements ICar{
//all variables has their own setters and getters
private String manufacturer;
private String plate;
private DateTime dateOfManufacture;
private int mileage;
private int ownerId;
private Owner owner; // will not be serialized to xml
.....
}


//code for serialize to xml
public static String serialize(Object obj)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(baos);
    encoder.writeObject(obj);
    encoder.close();        
    return baos.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I choose to use JAXB serialization with annotations. It was the best and easiest option. Thank all of you for your help.

```
public static String serialize(Object obj) throws JAXBException
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

    m.marshal(obj, writer);
    return writer.toString();
}

public static Object deserialize(String xml, Object obj) throws JAXBException
{
    StringBuffer xmlStr = new StringBuffer(xml);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

    return um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr.toString())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html#transient).  Here's an updated example.

```
BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Car.class);
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptors.length; ++i) {
    PropertyDescriptor pd = propertyDescriptors[i];
    if (pd.getName().equals("dateOfManufacture")) {
        pd.setValue("transient", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for serialization with the XmlEncoder since this is what the original poster is using?

Comment: @zdarsky.peter: look at [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html#transient) on how to mark a JavaBean property as being transient. Either that or serialize using JAXB and use the `@XmlTransient` annotation to mark a property as being transient.

Comment: I stand corrected, it looks like [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html#transient) is the only way to mark props transient with XMLEncoder.

Comment: I updated the example and added a link to the Oracle docs explaining transient fields with XMLEncoder.